Is it a good practice to manage SQLite connection in a DbContext class?
I am writing a program that uses SQLite, and it seemed strange to me to open and close the connection every time I use the database, so I decided to use this in the context class. Is this a normal practice, or can it cause problems?
For example:
using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace LUC.SqlFileTree
{
    public class SqlContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Item> items { get; set; }
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        private SqliteConnection connection;

        public SqlContext (string connectionString)
        {
            ConnectionString = connectionString;
            _ = Database.EnsureCreated();
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring (DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            ...
            connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionStringBuilder.ToString());
            connection.Open();
            ...
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating (ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            ...
        }

        public override void Dispose ()
        {
            connection.Close();

            SqliteConnection.ClearAllPools();
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);

            base.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

After that I work with the database like this:
using var context = new SqlContext(connectionString);
...

So far there have been no problems with this implementation, but I am afraid that in the future this approach will cause some bugs that will be difficult to find.
